# Unmarshal multiple data types in one key in goalng

Tags: go

I have JSON key which will have any one the below data.

1.{"value": "ve"}

2.{"value": ["ve","ff"]}

3.{"value": [1,2]}

4.{"value": 3}

How to unmarshal into a golang's struct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to just use interface{} in your struct.  See:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type decoded struct {
    Value interface{}       `json:"value"`
}

func decode(jstr string) {
    var val decoded
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(jstr), &val)
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", val.Value)
}

func main() {
    decode(`{"value": "ve"}`)
    decode(`{"value": ["ve","ff"]}`)
    decode(`{"value": [1,2]}`)
    decode(`{"value": 3}`)
}
```

You'll probably need to combine this with stuff in [the reflect package](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) or (as I did above) fmt.Sprintf() or similar to actually get at your data.  This is, however, good enough to decode and put in a structure:

```
$ ./spike 
ve
[ve ff]
[1 2]
3
```

Comment: Or just use simple [type assertions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions).